# Does native EE have good menuing options?

Tags: navee, taxonomy, menu

I've used Taxonomy or NavEE previously, but I'm now considering keeping it simple, if possible, and using native EE controls for menuing. Anybody have good solutions?   That is, something for my content author to use to manage the menu that isn't hard-coded templates. Perhaps some way of utilizing categories (the only thing I know of that has hierarchy)?

Answer (score 0):

I found Structure works well, it allows the user to add and move around pages easily and gives you way to generate menus: http://buildwithstructure.com/